# Hosting MP3 Files with Java

Tags: java, http, mp3

So I am trying to emulate something like what this site has set up:

http://www.ntonyx.com/mp3files/Morning_Flower.mp3

Where when a browser like chrome goes to this exact url, basically a player appears and you are able to 'stream' the music.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;

import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpExchange;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpHandler;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer;

public class WebServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(8000), 0);
        server.createContext("/test/file.mp3", new MyHandler());
        server.setExecutor(null); // creates a default executor
        server.start();
    }

    static class MyHandler implements HttpHandler {
        @Override
        public void handle(HttpExchange t) throws IOException {
            String response = "This is the response";
            t.sendResponseHeaders(200, response.length());
            OutputStream os = t.getResponseBody();
            os.write(response.getBytes());
            os.close();
        }
    }

}
```

I am trying to emulate this with some simple java code. Where I am struggling as figuring out how I should format the request to appear in this way. Is there a way to send a local file stored on my drive to the request? I have been struggling to find an example of how to do this

Comment: You can dump the bytes of the mp3 file into the stream. Most browsers will then buffer it for playback.

Comment: oh man, i have no idea how to do that

Comment: Look at [`FileInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/io/FileInputStream.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `FileInputStream` to read the bytes of your file to send to the browser:

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;

import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpExchange;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpHandler;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer;

public class WebServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(8000), 0);
        server.createContext("/test/file.mp3", new MyHandler());
        server.setExecutor(null); // creates a default executor
        server.start();
    }

    static class MyHandler implements HttpHandler {
        @Override
        public void handle(HttpExchange t) throws IOException {

            File file = new File("path/to/file.mp3");                 // Create a new File object pointing to your mp3 file   

            /* https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38679686/ :) */   
            t.getResponseHeaders().put("Content-Type", "audio/mpeg"); // Make sure the browser knows this is an audio file
            t.sendResponseHeaders(200, file.length());                // Send the length of the file to the browser

            FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(file);       // Open an InputStream to read your file
            OutputStream os = t.getResponseBody();
            byte[] buff = new byte[1024];                             // Create a small buffer to hold bytes as you read them
            int read = 0;                                             // Keep track of how many bytes you read

            // While there are still bytes to read, send them to the client
            while((read = stream.read(buff)) > 0) {
                os.write(buff, 0, read);
            }
            // Close the streams
            os.close();
            stream.close();
        }
    }

}
```